# Defining a struct imported from DLL works only when its constructor is defined in the header file

Tags: c++, dll, struct, linker, unresolved-external

**Problem**:

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall Vector3::Vector3(void)" (??0Vector3@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _WinMain@16

**Details**:

I have a custom Vector3 class with its basic constructor Vector3() which is declared in the Maths.h file:

```
    struct Vector3
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        Vector3();
     ...
     }
```

and defined in Maths.cpp:

```
    Vector3::Vector3()
    {
        this->x = 0;
        this->y = 0;
        this->z = 0;
    }
```

Module "Maths" is a part of a DLL. As long as I use the Vector3 class within the modules of the DLL it's business as usual. *However* in the specific case when I try to define it in the executable which links with the DLL, I get unresolved external symbol. E.g.:

```
    int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd)
    {
        ...
        Vector3 a = Vector3();
        ...
    }
```

**I have found a workaround**. If I perform the definition in the Maths.h itself and ommit it in Maths.cpp entirely, like this:

```
    struct Vector3
    {
        float x;
        float y;
        float z;

        Vector3()
        {
           this->x = 0;
           this->y = 0;
           this->z = 0;
        }
     ...
     }
```

it works. But I have no idea what the problem was and why it manifested itself only in this specific case.

Comment: Is the definition actually being exported? I ask because I don't see any macro machinery (or similar) in the `Vector` struct of your question.

Comment: If you creating a DLL with VS, check "Export Symbols".  It will create the relevant __declspec entries.  Have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a90k134d.aspx if you are not using Visual Studio

Comment: Okay I see, I was exporting the DLLfunctions being called from the platform layer(Init, Update and Release) by using "__declspec(dllexport)" semantic but that was it. So I either define the constructor in the header file which does it since the header file is inlined in th executable or I export it explicitly from the module, that means that the linker goes into the obj and searches for the definition and brings that to the executable. Am I understanding correctly? Thanks.